# No parameter error when parameters are given

Tags: python, discord.py, visual-glitch

Ok, so I got inspired by a lot of the Discord Bots out there so I decided to make my own economy commands. One of them, is the classic 'rob' command, where you can take money from people.
Here is my command, (wallet.json and bank.json are two different storage json files for money)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
...
...
@eco.command(name='withdraw')
@commands.cooldown(1, 10.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def withdraw(ctx, amount):
    print(amount)
    authorname = ctx.author.name + "#" + ctx.author.discriminator
    with open("wallet.json", "r") as w:
        wallet = json.load(w)
    with open("bank.json", "r") as b:
        bank = json.load(b)
    
    bank[str(authorname)] = bank[str(authorname)] - amount
    wallet[str(authorname)] = wallet[str(authorname)] + amount

    with open("wallet.json", "r") as w:
        json.dump(wallet, w, indent=4)
    with open("bank.json", "w") as b:
        json.dump(bank, b, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f':white_check_mark: Succesfully withdrew ${amount}')
```

I run the command and it provides me with this

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/laptop/Desktop/CURB/curb.py", line 234, in on_command_error
    await ctx.command.__call__(ctx, *ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: withdraw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/laptop/Desktop/CURB/curb.py", line 234, in on_command_error
    await ctx.command.__call__(ctx, *ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: withdraw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/laptop/Desktop/CURB/curb.py", line 234, in on_command_error
    await ctx.command.__call__(ctx, *ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: withdraw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'
```

For some reason, it says this while I clearly supply an argument. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Looked at the error again, and it says that there is an error in my on_command_error function. The only code in my on_command_error is:

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    #and this is the part where it says there's an error  
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):       
        if ctx.author==client.app_info.owner:
           await ctx.command.__call__(ctx, *ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)               
           return
```

So I removed that, but that was the code that ensured that only the owner can bypass the cooldown; which means I cannot bypass the cooldown since that was the code causing the problem, so it's kinda like a Catch 22. Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: How do you execute the command?

Comment: I execute the command saying `{prefix}rob @User`

so if the prefix was '!' and the User was CrazyMoosen, then I would execute like this:

`!rob @CrazyMoosen`

Comment: Also, I looked at the error again, and it says that there is an error in my `on_command_error` function. The only code in my on_command_error is  





`@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):  
...
...
#and this is the part where it says there's an error 
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):  
    if ctx.author==client.app_info.owner:  
            await ctx.command.__call__(ctx, *ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  
            return`  

So I removed that, but that means I cannot bypass the cooldown, so it's kinda like a Catch 22

Comment: You should add the updates to the post through editing.

Comment: what do you mean by that? oh - nvm i got what you mean